# How can I get the line of a table while I got its address

Tags: lua

```
local a = {'1'}
b = {'2'}
print('--------a:', a)   --------a: table: 002411A0
print('--------b:', b)   --------b: table: 005BC470
```

how can I get like:   `a.lua:1  in table a`
or `a.lua:2  in table b`
while I know the table address (002411A0)
my lua environment is lua5.1, I don't know if I need to read the source or compiled of lua5.1？

Comment: I know debug.getinfo can get the line info of function ,but table seem cannot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are prepared to declare your tables with a helper function, called, say `logger`, you can achieve your goal.

The idea is to record the line in a virtual table field `__line`. In the example below I do it using `__index` metamethod, but you can simply add a field to the created table.

The line number is obtained by `debug.getinfo (2).currentline`. The choice of `2` is determined by the call stack depth in my example.

```lua
local function logged (t)
    local line = debug.getinfo (2).currentline
    return setmetatable (t, {
        __index = function (_, key)
            if key == '__line' then
                return line
            end
        end
    })
end

local a = logged {'1'}
print (a.__line)    -- 12
b = logged {'2'}
print (b.__line)    -- 14
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a line where the table is defined by using its address (as the line in the source code and the address in memory have no relationship). What you can do is to parse the source code of your script and find where the definition of the table is, but I'm not sure what use it's going to have for you. Maybe you can describe what you are trying to do?

If you indeed want to find where the table is defined, you can use something like [metalua](https://github.com/fab13n/metalua) that builds abstract syntax tree (AST) of your code fragment that you can then traverse to find where a particular table is defined.

Another option is to parse the output of `luac` compiler, which will allow you to find what line the NEWTABLE command for a particular table is on.

Comment: thanks a lot.I want code a tool to back-track my code(I donot know the technical word,it just like debug.traceback which can tell me the track of fuction), but when I try to know the line of table(which store configuration information of some function,and I want to locate it) , I got trouble.Maybe I need to learn how to bulid AST as you mention，or maybe I need figure out why debug.traceback can get the line of function for as reference?    Thank you for your reply!